# Can't show preferences dialog

Tags: python, application-development, quickly, python-2.7

I'm having some trouble with Python, again. I created a project using Quickly, and it created a preferences dialog for me. I am now trying to build up the preferences dialog, but I always get some error pointing me at a piece of code Quickly generated itself.

```
robin@RobinJ:~/Ubuntu One/Python/gtkreddit$ quickly run
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:391: Warning: g_object_set_property: construct property "type" for object `Window' can't be set after construction
  Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)
WARNING:gtkreddit_lib: connect_signals() 'expected handler 'btnRefresh_clicked' in /home/robin/Ubuntu One/Python/gtkreddit/gtkreddit/GtkredditWindow.pyc'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/gtkreddit", line 33, in <module>
    gtkreddit.main()
  File "/home/robin/Ubuntu One/Python/gtkreddit/gtkreddit/__init__.py", line 33, in main
    window = GtkredditWindow.GtkredditWindow()
  File "/home/robin/Ubuntu One/Python/gtkreddit/gtkreddit_lib/Window.py", line 35, in __new__
    new_object.finish_initializing(builder)
  File "/home/robin/Ubuntu One/Python/gtkreddit/gtkreddit/GtkredditWindow.py", line 50, in finish_initializing
    dlgPreferences = PreferencesDialog ()
  File "/home/robin/Ubuntu One/Python/gtkreddit/gtkreddit_lib/PreferencesDialog.py", line 26, in __new__
    new_object.finish_initializing(builder)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'finish_initializing'
```

This is the piece it is complaining about;

```
def finish_initializing(self, builder): # pylint: disable=E1002
    """Set up the preferences dialog"""
    super(PreferencesGtkredditDialog, self).finish_initializing(builder)
```

The entire code can be found [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~robinj/gtkreddit/trunk/files/33).

Please assist. I'm pretty new to Python.

Comment: Did you rename your preferences dialog in Glade?

Comment: @mhall119 Erm... I believe I did. What's the default name again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base class for the [Preferences dialog](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~robinj/gtkreddit/trunk/view/head:/gtkreddit_lib/PreferencesDialog.py) is looking for an object named `preferences_gtkreddit_dialog`, you need to either rename the dialog back to that.

In addition, somehow your [PreferencesGtkredditDialog Glade file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~robinj/gtkreddit/trunk/view/head:/data/ui/PreferencesGtkredditDialog.ui#L10) has been changed to think it is an instance of `GtkDialog`, where it should be an instance of `PreferencesGtkredditDialog`.

Comment: Not fixed yet. http://paste.ubuntu.com/1060918/

Comment: Can you push the latest code your your branch on Lanchpad so I can check it again?

Comment: Done. http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~robinj/gtkreddit/trunk/files